# How do I register an irc channel that I'm not an OP of?

Tags: irc, freenode

I made a channel on freenode that some friends started using.. eventually I lose my op privs as I leave/join with other non-ops still in the channel. Now i'm trying to register the channel but I have no way of becoming an op! How do I get around this problem?

This question applies to common irc daemons like inspircd or unrealircd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a channel with one hash in front, you need to register as a group. If it starts with two hashes, the process is easier.

Either way, join #freenode and poke us about it.