# How to register a freenode channel with no op

Tags: irc, freenode

This is a duplicate of the old question [How do I register an irc channel that I'm not an OP of?](https://superuser.com/questions/355756/how-do-i-register-an-irc-channel-that-im-not-an-op-of).  We made a channel yesterday, people joined, and today we're in the situation where there is no op on the channel but we'd like to register it.  We can't seem to find a workaround for the chicken-and-egg problem of registering the channel and needing to become op.

The old question doesn't have an answer that is helpful enough.  If anyone can help us, he's welcome.  If we find the needed information, e.g. from #freenode, we'll post it here as an answer in the hope to help future people :-)

Comment: Have you tried asking in #freenode as suggested in the answer to the other question?

Comment: Yes, but didn't get any reply.  I may try again and post a self-answer here if I eventually get one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I register an irc channel that I'm not an OP of?](https://superuser.com/questions/355756/how-do-i-register-an-irc-channel-that-im-not-an-op-of)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can simply ask in #freenode for someone to give you operator permissions.  Once they do that then you can go ahead and register the channel.  Note that they check if you represent a group or project using that name outside of freenode (at least if the channel is called "#project" and not "##project").